# ライブラリのバージョンの互換性の調べ方

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, flask

環境構築上の初歩的な質問をさせていただきたいと思います。

現在AIを用いたマイクロサービスアプリケーションのデプロイをしたくてanaconda navigatorを使用し、環境構築をしています。
ところが、互換性がないという旨のエラーが表示されてしまい、先の工程に進むことができません。
ChatGPTに質問して互換性のあるバージョンを表示してもらっても同様のエラーが出ます。
皆さまは環境を構築する際、どのように互換性のあるバージョンを調べているかご教示いただければ助かります。

OSはMacで使用するライブラリは以下の通り
python
Flask
gunicorn
h5py
Jinja2
Keras
numpy
Pillow
tensorflow
Werkzeug

ChatGPTで推奨されたバージョン

> それぞれのソフトウェアの最新のバージョンは以下の通りです。
>
> Python: 3.10.2
> Flask: 2.1.0
> Gunicorn: 20.1.0
> h5py: 3.4.0
> Jinja2: 3.0.2
> Keras: 2.8.0
> NumPy: 1.22.2
> Pillow: 9.0.0
> TensorFlow: 2.8.0
> Werkzeug: 2.1.0

お答え頂いた内容をもとにバージョンの変更をいたしました。
flask 2.1.3
jinja2 3.1.2
python 3.9.11
werkzeug 2.2.2
gunicorn 20.1.0
pillow 9.4.0 
numpy 1.20.1
tensorflow 2.9.1
h5py 3.5.0
keras 2.9.0

以下のエラーが発生しています。（字数制限のため、コメントの方にも記述いたします）

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package readline conflicts for:
python==3.9.11 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> readline[version='7.*|>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
sqlite -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> readline[version='7.*|>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> readline[version='7.*|>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
readline
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> readline[version='7.*|>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> readline[version='7.*|>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']

Package tk conflicts for:
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> tk[version='>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> tk[version='>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
tk
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']

Package numpy conflicts for:
h5py==3.5.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.16.6,<2.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1
keras==2.9.0 -> keras-preprocessing[version='>=1.1.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.16,<1.23|>=1.9.1|>=1.21,<1.23|>=1.21.2,<1.23.0|>=1.16.6,<1.23.0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorboard=2.10 -> numpy[version='>=1.12.0|>=1.20']

Package ncurses conflicts for:
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
sqlite -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
sqlite -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
readline -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> ncurses[version='>=6.3,<7.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
ncurses
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0|>=6.4,<7.0a0']

Package libgfortran5 conflicts for:
keras==2.9.0 -> scipy=1.7.3 -> libgfortran5[version='>=11.2.0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> libopenblas[version='>=0.3.3,<1.0a0'] -> libgfortran5[version='>=11.2.0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.16.6,<2.0a0'] -> libgfortran5[version='>=11.2.0']

Package sqlite conflicts for:
sqlite
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> sqlite[version='>=3.37.2,<4.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.37.2,<4.0a0|>=3.39.3,<4.0a0|>=3.40.0,<4.0a0|>=3.40.1,<4.0a0|>=3.39.2,<4.0a0|>=3.38.3,<4.0a0|>=3.38.2,<4.0a0']

Package tzdata conflicts for:
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
tzdata
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
wheel -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.9 -> tzdata
python==3.9.11 -> tzdata

Package jpeg conflicts for:
pillow==9.4.0 -> jpeg[version='>=9e,<10a']
pillow==9.4.0 -> lcms2[version='>=2.12,<3.0a0'] -> jpeg[version='>=9b,<10a|>=9d,<10a']

Package h5py conflicts for:
h5py==3.5.0
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorflow-base==2.10.0=eigen_py38h61e1807_0 -> h5py[version='>=3.1.0']

Package libcxx conflicts for:
python==3.9.11 -> libcxx[version='>=12.0.0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
readline -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1']
pillow==9.4.0 -> libtiff[version='>=4.2.0,<5.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=4.0.1']
libffi -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=4.0.1']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
pillow==9.4.0 -> libcxx[version='>=14.0.6']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=4.0.1|>=14.0.6|>=12.0.0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
libcxx
numpy==1.20.1 -> mkl_fft -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=4.0.1|>=14.0.6']
sqlite -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=4.0.1|>=14.0.6']
pip -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
python==3.9.11 -> libffi[version='>=3.3,<3.4.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=4.0.1']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
h5py==3.5.0 -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.6,<1.10.7.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=12.0.0|>=14.0.6|>=4.0.1']

Package libffi conflicts for:
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0|>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0|>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0|>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> libffi[version='>=3.3,<3.4.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0|>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5|>=3.4,<4.0a0']
libffi

Package openssl conflicts for:
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a']
python==3.9.11 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a']
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a']
openssl
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a']
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a']

Package markupsafe conflicts for:
jinja2==3.1.2 -> markupsafe[version='>=2.0']
flask==2.1.3 -> jinja2[version='>=3.0'] -> markupsafe[version='>=2.0|>=2.1.1']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> markupsafe[version='>=2.1.1']

Package xz conflicts for:
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> libtiff[version='>=4.2.0,<5.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
xz
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']

Package certifi conflicts for:
wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
certifi
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
openssl -> ca-certificates
pip -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
setuptools -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
certifi -> python -> ca-certificates
wheel -> python -> ca-certificates
python==3.9.11 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
ca-certificates

Package zlib conflicts for:
pillow==9.4.0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> sqlite[version='>=3.37.2,<4.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<2.0a0']
pillow==9.4.0 -> freetype[version='>=2.10.4,<3.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']
python==3.9.11 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
h5py==3.5.0 -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.6,<1.10.7.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
tk -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']
zlib
sqlite -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<2.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']

Package typing_extensions conflicts for:
flask==2.1.3 -> importlib-metadata[version='>=3.6.0'] -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.6.4']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorflow-base==2.10.0=eigen_py38h61e1807_0 -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.7.4']

Package bzip2 conflicts for:
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.10 -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']

Package pip conflicts for:
werkzeug==2.2.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> pip
h5py==3.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> pip
numpy==1.20.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> pip
wheel -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> pip
pillow==9.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> pip
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> pip
pip
python==3.9.11 -> pip
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> python=3.8 -> pip
keras==2.9.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> pip
flask==2.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> pip
jinja2==3.1.2 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> pip
certifi -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> pip
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> pip

Package six conflicts for:
numpy==1.20.1 -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> six
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorflow-base==2.10.0=eigen_py38h61e1807_0 -> six[version='>=1.15.0']
keras==2.9.0 -> keras-preprocessing[version='>=1.1.2'] -> six[version='>=1.9.0']
（以下コメント）
```

質問に慣れておらず、必要な情報があれば追記いたしますので、
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーログというかメッセージというかがあるなら勝手な翻訳とか抽出とかせず一言一句そのまま追記してみよう（プライバシー情報が入っていたらそこだけ隠蔽するのはあり）

Comment: 大抵のライブラリ等は依存関係のバージョン情報をリリースノートで提示しているので、必要に応じてそれらも確認しましょう。 / ChatGPT は **2021年末** 時点のデータを元に回答するので、情報を鵜呑みにしない方がよいです。23年3月時点でざっと搔い摘んでも Python 3.11.2, Flask 2.2.3, Keras 2.11.0 が最新版です。

Comment: Anaconda環境でもツールがあるようですね。最初の質問や回答は古いですが、割と新し目の追加回答が付いています。[How to identify conda package dependents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26101972/9014308)

Comment: ＜エラーログの続き1＞
Package wheel conflicts for:
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorboard=2.10 -> wheel[version='>=0.26|>=0.35,<0.36']
python==3.9.11 -> pip -> wheel
wheel
pip -> wheel

Package libpng conflicts for:
pillow==9.4.0 -> freetype[version='>=2.10.4,<3.0a0'] -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorflow-base==2.10.0=eigen_py38h61e1807_0 -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']

Package werkzeug conflicts for:
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorboard=2.10 -> werkzeug[version='>=1.0.1']
flask==2.1.3 -> werkzeug[version='>=2.0']
werkzeug==2.2.2

Comment: ＜エラーログの続き2＞
Package setuptools conflicts for:
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorboard=2.10 -> setuptools[version='>=41.0.0']
flask==2.1.3 -> jinja2[version='>=3.0'] -> setuptools
wheel -> setuptools
python==3.9.11 -> pip -> setuptools
pip -> setuptools
setuptools
gunicorn==20.1.0 -> setuptools

Package jinja2 conflicts for:
flask==2.1.3 -> jinja2[version='>=3.0']
jinja2==3.1.2

Package keras conflicts for:
tensorflow==2.10.0 -> tensorflow-base==2.10.0=eigen_py38h61e1807_0 -> keras=2.10
keras==2.9.0

Comment: ＜エラーログの続き3＞ 
Package numpy-base conflicts for:
numpy==1.20.1 -> mkl_fft -> numpy-base[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0|>=1.2.1,<2.0a0|>=1.0.2,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4,<2.0a0']
numpy==1.20.1 -> numpy-base==1.20.1[build='py39h585ceec_0|py37h585ceec_0|py39h3a452eb_0|py38h585ceec_0|py38h3a452eb_0|py37h3a452eb_0']

Package mkl_fft conflicts for:
numpy==1.20.1 -> mkl_fft
h5py==3.5.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.16.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_fft[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0|>=1.2.1,<2.0a0']

Comment: ＜エラーログの続き4＞
Package libcxxabi conflicts for:
libffi -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi==4.0.1[build='hcfea43d_1|hebd6815_0']
ncurses -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi==4.0.1[build='hcfea43d_1|hebd6815_0']
libcxx -> libcxxabi==4.0.1[build='hcfea43d_1|hebd6815_0']

Comment: もしかしたらこの記事が参考になるかもしれませんね。[Tensorflowインストールエラーで結局MacにAnaconda再インストールしてうまくいった話](https://pala-ghe.com/tensorflow-reinstall/)

Comment: この問題は、@kunifさんが提示したURLの内容の通り、環境をクリーンにするのが一番良いと思います。ただ単にアンインストールだけではうまくいかないケースがあります。先にインストールしていた環境下でパッケージのフォルダだけ生き残っていて、再インストールしても同じ問題が発生します。Windows でも体験しました。インストールフォルダ（AppDataも含め）が分かれば、アンインストールしたあと、それらのフォルダに残されたパッケージ関連と思しきフォルダ・ファイルを全消去してください。

Comment: 一度optフォルダとAnacondaNavigator関連ファイルを全て削除、Anacondaを再インストールしてflaskとpythonの該当バージョンのみを仮想環境上に構築することで正常に動作いたしました。後は機械学習ライブラリのバージョン互換を調べる必要がありますが、仮想環境上に構築する際のバージョンの調べ方という点で解決済みにしたいと思います、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anaconda navigator環境で試行してみました。
conda環境でもpipdeptreeが使用できます。

## 前提条件

指定されたパッケージを新しく作った仮想環境でインストールする。
その再利用するコマンドは以下

```
conda install -c conda-forge (パッケージ名)=(指定バージョン)
```

次いで、pipdeptreeをインストール

```
conda install -c conda-forge pipdeptree
```

## 結果

```
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2022.12.7
Flask==2.1.0
  - click [required: >=8.0, installed: 8.1.3]
    - colorama [required: Any, installed: 0.4.6]
  - itsdangerous [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.1.2]
  - Jinja2 [required: >=3.0, installed: 3.0.2]
    - MarkupSafe [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.1.1]
  - Werkzeug [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.1.0]
h5py==3.4.0
  - numpy [required: >=1.19.0, installed: 1.22.2]
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
  - zipp [required: >=0.5, installed: 3.15.0]
keras==2.8.0
Pillow==9.0.0
pip==23.0.1
pipdeptree==2.5.2
setuptools==65.6.3
wheel==0.38.4
wincertstore==0.2
```

### 気になること

gunicornがPackagesNotFoundErrorでインストールできませんでした。
anaconda.orgには、以下のコマンドのいずれかを試すように記されています。

```
conda install -c conda-forge gunicorn
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf201901" gunicorn
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" gunicorn
```

全てダメでした。

### 推察

condaパッケージとpipパッケージを混同して利用しているのではないでしょうか？
これらはお互い同じパッケージ名があるものがあり、依存関係が相互に干渉しあわないそうです。
しかし、名称が同じであるため、本来pipでのパッケージが使いたいという意図だとしても、condaのパッケージを参照しに行ってしまったりしているのではいでしょうか？

おそらく、原因はgunicornにあると思われますので、その辺を調査されてはいかがでしょうか？
試していませんが、conda環境でのpipでもpipdeptreeがインストールでき、依存関係は調べられると思います。

condaとpipで比較されてはいかがでしょうか？

### 追記

ローカル環境でのgunicornをインストールしてpipdeptreeで結果を見てみました。

```
gunicorn==20.1.0
  - setuptools [required: >=3.0, installed: 58.1.0]
```

特に問題となりそうな依存関係ではないと思われます。

Comment: anaconda.orgのGunicornは、その表記の上にlinuxとosxしか載っていないので確認したのがwindowsだったら使えなさそうです。そうすると質問者さんのOSがそれらか、あるいはgoogle colabとかかもしれませんね。

Comment: なるほどですね。ただ、依存関係はこの通りで調べられそうですけどね。

Comment: google colaboでもpipdeptreeをインストールすれば、依存関係を出力することができました。

Comment: OSは何かという指摘があったので質問文に追記いたしました。
仮想環境構築はAnacondaNvigatorのGUIで行っており、
ご教示いただきましたpipdeptreeを使用しながら、何回かに分けてライブラリをインストールしてみました。
結果、flask 2.1.3, jinja2 3.1.2, python 3.9.11, werkzeug 2.2.2, gunicorn 20.1.0, pillow2.9.0 が正常にインストールできるとわかりました。(pipは23.0.1です)
一方で仮想環境にApplyする前に"Multiple Errors Encounterd"がnumpy, tensorflow, h5py, kerasで発生しています。入念に検証頂いたこともあり解決済みとしたいのですが、これらのソリューションを募集中としています。

Comment: 本質問とはズレがあるかと思いますが、pipとcondaなどの管理パッケージから独立的な環境を選択するため現状の構造にしたのですが、ローカル環境とAnacondaNavigatorで作成した仮想環境において相互依存性はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: anconda環境で、パッケージのインストール方法にcondaコマンドとpipコマンドがあり、重複したパッケージがあります。推奨はcondaコマンドとなっており、condaに用意されていない場合には、pipを検討するようにとのことです。

Comment: したがって、pcローカル環境のはなしではないです。

Comment: Macはよく分からないですが、anconda navi自体を管理者権限で起動する必要があるようです。

Comment: 質問のコメントで指摘のあるように、互換性がないという旨のエラーとは、どういう表示なのか、表示された内容をそのままコピペした方が良いと思います。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、エラーメッセージをそのまま掲載いたしました。
改善の際にはまた本文を修正したいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

意図されている内容とずれているかもしれませんが、依存関係を調べるパッケージがあります。

## インストール

```
python -m pip install pipdeptree
```

## 実行

```
pipdeptree > (出力するテキストファイル).txt
```

もちろんテキストファイルに出力しなくても良いのですが、結果が残って振り返りやすいので、テキスト出力をしたほうが便利です。

## 実行結果の例

```
autopep8==2.0.2
  - pycodestyle [required: >=2.10.0, installed: 2.10.0]
  - tomli [required: Any, installed: 2.0.1]
flake8==6.0.0
  - mccabe [required: >=0.7.0,<0.8.0, installed: 0.7.0]
  - pycodestyle [required: >=2.10.0,<2.11.0, installed: 2.10.0]
  - pyflakes [required: >=3.0.0,<3.1.0, installed: 3.0.1]
pip-licenses==4.1.0
  - prettytable [required: >=2.3.0, installed: 3.6.0]
    - wcwidth [required: Any, installed: 0.2.6]
pip-review==1.3.0
  - packaging [required: Any, installed: 23.0]
  - pip [required: Any, installed: 23.0.1]
pipdeptree==2.5.2
pyinstaller==5.9.0
  - altgraph [required: Any, installed: 0.17.3]
  - pefile [required: >=2022.5.30, installed: 2023.2.7]
  - pyinstaller-hooks-contrib [required: >=2021.4, installed: 2023.0]
  - pywin32-ctypes [required: >=0.2.0, installed: 0.2.0]
  - setuptools [required: >=42.0.0, installed: 58.1.0]
pywin32==305
wheel==0.38.4
```

このように、自分でインストールしたパッケージが依存しているパッケージをツリーで表示してくれます。そこには指定されたバージョンも記載されます。

使用しているパッケージにより、この紐づいたパッケージの要求バージョンが異なり、同時に使えないものが存在します。

Comment: ローカル環境での構築では有効だと思いますが、Anaconda Navigatorで仮想環境の構築を前提としているので、本パッケージを使用することができないケースにあります。

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda3 環境は(pipなどとは別に) 独自にパッケージを管理しています
質問の意図がよく読めないけれど
普通に `conda`コマンドでパッケージをインストールすれば互換性は取れます。

(パッケージ依存関係: pandas 1.5.3 の例)

```bash
$ conda search pandas=1.5.3 --info
Loading channels: done
pandas 1.5.3 py310h1128e8f_0
----------------------------
file name   : pandas-1.5.3-py310h1128e8f_0.conda
name        : pandas
version     : 1.5.3
build       : py310h1128e8f_0
build number: 0
size        : 12.0 MB
license     : BSD-3-Clause
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/pandas-1.5.3-py310h1128e8f_0.conda
md5         : c35f8ea378f1aa91cb9a4037a7a43fc2
timestamp   : 2023-03-03 09:41:17 UTC
constraints :
  - xarray >=0.19.0
  - matplotlib-base >=3.3.2
  - fastparquet >=0.4.0
  - numba >=0.53.1
  - xlsxwriter >=1.4.3
  - lxml >=4.6.3
  - pytables >=3.6.1
  - scipy >=1.7.1
  - blosc >=1.21.0
  - pandas-gbq >=0.15.0
  - zstandard >=0.15.2
  - xlwt >=1.3.0
  - html5lib >=1.1
  - xlrd >=2.0.1
  - psycopg2 >=2.8.6
  - openpyxl >=3.0.7
  - pyreadstat >=1.1.2
  - gcsfs >=2021.7.0
  - pyxlsb >=1.0.8
  - tzdata >=2022a
  - python-snappy >=0.6.0
  - fsspec >=2021.7.0
  - sqlalchemy >=1.4.16
  - pyarrow >=1.0.1
  - s3fs >=2021.08.0
  - pymysql >=1.0.2
  - tabulate >=0.8.9
  - beautifulsoup4 >=4.9.3
  - brotli >=0.7.0
  - jinja2 >=3.0.0
dependencies:
  - bottleneck >=1.3.2
  - libgcc-ng >=11.2.0
  - libstdcxx-ng >=11.2.0
  - numexpr >=2.7.3
  - numpy >=1.21,<2.0a0
  - python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0
  - python-dateutil >=2.8.1
  - pytz >=2020.1
```

---

Ubuntuでの環境構築の例:

```bash
$ conda create -n keras python=3.10 flask=2.1 gunicorn=20.1 h5py=3 jinja2=3 keras=2.8 numpy=1.22 pillow=9 tensorflow=2.8 werkzeug
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/USER/anaconda3/envs/keras

  added / updated specs:
    - flask=2.1
    - gunicorn=20.1
    - h5py=3
    - jinja2=3
    - keras=2.8
    - numpy=1.22
    - pillow=9
    - python=3.10
    - tensorflow=2.8
    - werkzeug


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _libgcc_mutex-0.1          |             main           3 KB
    _openmp_mutex-5.1          |            1_gnu          21 KB
    _tflow_select-2.3.0        |              mkl           2 KB
    abseil-cpp-20211102.0      |       hd4dd3e8_0        1020 KB
    absl-py-1.3.0              |  py310h06a4308_0         168 KB
    aiohttp-3.8.3              |  py310h5eee18b_0         455 KB
    aiosignal-1.2.0            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          12 KB
    astunparse-1.6.3           |             py_0          17 KB
    async-timeout-4.0.2        |  py310h06a4308_0          12 KB
    attrs-22.1.0               |  py310h06a4308_0          86 KB
    blas-1.0                   |              mkl           6 KB
    blinker-1.4                |  py310h06a4308_0          21 KB
    brotlipy-0.7.0             |py310h7f8727e_1002         712 KB
    c-ares-1.19.0              |       h5eee18b_0         118 KB
    cachetools-4.2.2           |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          13 KB
    certifi-2022.12.7          |  py310h06a4308_0         150 KB
    cffi-1.15.1                |  py310h5eee18b_3         243 KB
    click-8.0.4                |  py310h06a4308_0         156 KB
    cryptography-39.0.1        |  py310h9ce1e76_0         1.4 MB
    flask-2.1.3                |  py310h06a4308_0         131 KB
(中略)
    tensorflow-2.8.2           |mkl_py310hd2b8f8c_0           4 KB
    tensorflow-base-2.8.2      |mkl_py310hf890080_0        85.4 MB
    tensorflow-estimator-2.8.0 |  py310h2f386ee_0         532 KB
    termcolor-2.1.0            |  py310h06a4308_0          11 KB
    typing_extensions-4.4.0    |  py310h06a4308_0          46 KB
    urllib3-1.26.14            |  py310h06a4308_0         197 KB
    werkzeug-2.2.3             |  py310h06a4308_0         346 KB
    wheel-0.38.4               |  py310h06a4308_0          64 KB
    wrapt-1.14.1               |  py310h5eee18b_0          81 KB
    yarl-1.8.1                 |  py310h5eee18b_0         212 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       209.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _libgcc_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main
  _openmp_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_openmp_mutex-5.1-1_gnu
  _tflow_select      pkgs/main/linux-64::_tflow_select-2.3.0-mkl
  abseil-cpp         pkgs/main/linux-64::abseil-cpp-20211102.0-hd4dd3e8_0
  absl-py            pkgs/main/linux-64::absl-py-1.3.0-py310h06a4308_0
  aiohttp            pkgs/main/linux-64::aiohttp-3.8.3-py310h5eee18b_0
  aiosignal          pkgs/main/noarch::aiosignal-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  appdirs            pkgs/main/noarch::appdirs-1.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  astunparse         pkgs/main/noarch::astunparse-1.6.3-py_0
  async-timeout      pkgs/main/linux-64::async-timeout-4.0.2-py310h06a4308_0
  attrs              pkgs/main/linux-64::attrs-22.1.0-py310h06a4308_0
  blas               pkgs/main/linux-64::blas-1.0-mkl
(中略)
  sqlite             pkgs/main/linux-64::sqlite-3.41.1-h5eee18b_0
  tensorboard        pkgs/main/linux-64::tensorboard-2.8.0-py310h06a4308_0
  tensorboard-data-~ pkgs/main/linux-64::tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1-py310h52d8a92_0
  tensorboard-plugi~ pkgs/main/linux-64::tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.1-py310h06a4308_0
  tensorflow         pkgs/main/linux-64::tensorflow-2.8.2-mkl_py310hd2b8f8c_0
  tensorflow-base    pkgs/main/linux-64::tensorflow-base-2.8.2-mkl_py310hf890080_0
  tensorflow-estima~ pkgs/main/linux-64::tensorflow-estimator-2.8.0-py310h2f386ee_0
  termcolor          pkgs/main/linux-64::termcolor-2.1.0-py310h06a4308_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/linux-64::tk-8.6.12-h1ccaba5_0
  typing_extensions  pkgs/main/linux-64::typing_extensions-4.4.0-py310h06a4308_0
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2022g-h04d1e81_0
  urllib3            pkgs/main/linux-64::urllib3-1.26.14-py310h06a4308_0
  werkzeug           pkgs/main/linux-64::werkzeug-2.2.3-py310h06a4308_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/linux-64::wheel-0.38.4-py310h06a4308_0
  wrapt              pkgs/main/linux-64::wrapt-1.14.1-py310h5eee18b_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/linux-64::xz-5.2.10-h5eee18b_1
  yaml               pkgs/main/linux-64::yaml-0.2.5-h7b6447c_0
  yarl               pkgs/main/linux-64::yarl-1.8.1-py310h5eee18b_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/linux-64::zlib-1.2.13-h5eee18b_0
  zstd               pkgs/main/linux-64::zstd-1.5.2-ha4553b6_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```